# Can't start a process from another process

Tags: c#, batch-file, visual-studio-2012, xna, xna-4.0

I've created a form application and an XNA application. I'm trying to make it so that when a button is pressed on the form it will open the XNA application in a seperate window. I am attempting this by launching the .exe file of the XNA application.

However, when doing so nothing happens. The console output in Visual Studio only shows "The thread 0xyyyy has exited with code 0 (0x0)." and the XNA application never appears. The weird thing is that when I manually run the .exe it works just  fine.

I have also attempted creating a .bat file to start the XNA application. Launching the .bat launches the XNA application just fine when I do it manually, but when lauching the .bat from the form it just appears and dissapears without anything happening.

Code to run the .bat file:

```
   private void viewGame(object o, EventArgs ea)
    {
        Process.Start(@"C:\Path_To_Project\bin\x86\Debug\StartVisualiser.bat");
    }
```

The .bat file itself:

```
start HelikopterVisual.exe 
exit
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: perhaps you need to show more code than what you have also there is a thing called `Google` you could do a simple google search on `C# Process.Start XNA` here is a starting point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434477/process-start-and-trying-to-launch-a-game

Comment: Hello MethodMan, I already searched on Google but I didn't manage to find that question. Thank you, setting a working directory fixed the issue!

Comment: funny how setting how I was able to find it in less than a second.. and the link also showed a directory / working directory.. good thing you fixed it..